# Where to place PhantomJS executable for Python Selenium Webdriver to work?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am on a mac and I am trying to use selenium with phantomjs. I have downloaded the phantomjs executable for mac from their website, and I don't know where to place it for selenium to use it. I am using Visual Studio Code, a Mac and python 3.7. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it anywhere! Yes anywhere. Even i place it in a separate folder named setups where i store all webdrivers including `PhantomJS.exe` also. It works well. No errors.

Just add it to the path in the code itself :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\setups\PhantomJS.exe")
```

Either use `PhantomJS.exe` after the path name just like i did it above or use `PhantomJS` only.

**Edit :**
`PhantomJS` support has been ended recently because it's too old, and is no longer maintaining. The message you are getting is not an error, it's a warning. I prefer you using chrome browser here.

You can even make chrome browser `headless` just like `PhantomJS`.
To do that :

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Also don't forget to use `options=options` in the end of the path just like i did.

Comment: Selenium says that it cannot use PhantonJS. Something about it being too old. How can I fix this?

Comment: I recently updated my answer. Please do check that, and if solved then please mark it as accepted.